# How to verify Logjam issue with openssl command?

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, owasp, diffie-hellman

My application is being reported that having vulnerability issue, which is the `SSL/TLS Diffie-Hellman Modulus <= 1024 bits (Logjam) CVE-2015-4000`.

Based on [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278896) link, there is a solution to edit the `java.security` file to solve this issue.

I would like to test on it, but I am not sure how to verify it. I would like to see the different before my changes and after my changes.

I found a command from [this](https://tools.keycdn.com/logjam) link,

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443
```

I run this command and I get some info, but I am not sure how to verify my website is having Logjam issue or not. (`SSL/TLS Diffie-Hellman Modulus <= 1024 bits`). And how to check If my changes have overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [Qualys SSL Labs tools](https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html), an example can be found [At Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https).

The test for a server can be found on this [link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and the [User Agent Capabilities](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/index.html) is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid logjam, we need to do the following:

- Disable Export Cipher Suites
  run this and confirm that the connection is not established

openssl s_client -connect [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443) -cipher "EXP"

- Deploy (Ephemeral) Elliptic-Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE)

openssl s_client -connect [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443) -cipher "EDH" | grep "Server Temp Key"

- Use a Strong, Diffie Hellman Group.

https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html